# Delete a row from a table which contains the primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables called `distance` and `place` as follows:

**distance**

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ name ║ point ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ Call ║   A   ║
║ 2  ║ Foo  ║   B   ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

**place**

```
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ point ║ address ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║   A   ║  ABCD   ║
║   B   ║  CDEF   ║
╚═══════╩═════════╝
```

'id' is the primary key of the 'distance' table and 'point' is the primary key of the 'place' table. 'point' is the foreign key of the 'distance' table which is referred by the 'place' table.
I want to delete the row of point 'A' from 'place' table which is the **id** is equals to '1'. As this foreign key is created with 'on delete cascade constraint', the relevant row of the place table should also be deleted.
(That means, according to the following tables, the first row of the distance table and the first row of the place table should be deleted).

This is the query I have tried so far under PHP code:

```
mysql_query("delete p.point from place p where p.point IN SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.point FROM distance d GROUP BY d.point where d.id='1' )");
```

But, this does not delete the rows. No error messages.
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `mysql_query` is depreciated / removed depending on you PHP version - have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
DELETE p.* FROM place p
INNER JOIN distance d ON p.point = d.point
WHERE d.id = 1;
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Comment: If You Think This Answer Is Useful Mark Vote Up  to useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `INNER JOIN` in your `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE p FROM place p
INNER JOIN distance d ON p.point = d.point
WHERE (d.id = 1);
```

Comment: I dont think you need `DELETE p.*` it could be just `DELETE p from ...`

Answer (score 0):

You use `*` in your `WHERE IN` statement. You need to select only ids if you want to use `WHERE IN`. Here's your fixed code:

```
mysql_query("delete p from place p where p.point IN (SELECT p.point FROM (SELECT d.point FROM distance d GROUP BY d.point where d.id='1' ))");
```

But i don't understand why to use two select when you can do just like this

```
mysql_query("delete p from place p where p.point IN (SELECT d.point FROM distance d GROUP BY d.point where d.id='1' )");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution1: 
You are missing "(" after in clause in your query.

Solution2: Better option is join-

```
delete pl.* from place pl 
join distance dst on dst.point=pl.point 
where d.id=1;
```

Solution3: Best option will be just delete from parent table and all related rows will be deleted automatically from child as you are using on delete cascade functionality.

```
DELETE FROM place WHERE `point`='A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
DELETE FROM place p
WHERE p.point IN (SELECT d.point 
                  FROM distance d 
                 WHERE d.id=1)
```

So the PHP Query should be like this

`mysql_query('DELETE FROM place p WHERE p.point IN (SELECT d.point FROM distance d WHERE d.id=1)')`

The Sub-Sub Select you have done probably is returning no value, so no action is made and no error is given because the query is done correctly.